# Replace :hover with onclick

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have an accordion slider which expands the image where the mouse hovers over with pure CSS :hover; however, I would like to add the same effect when the image is clicked on by the left mouse button (or touched on a touchscreen) and stay at the same "style" or "state" as when it is being hover'ed on (expanded). Thanks in advance from a coding newbie!

```js
<script>
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("null");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
         
  });
}
 </script>
```

```css
.accordion ul li div a p {
 position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) { background-image: url("pic1.jpg"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) { background-image: url("pic2.jpg"); background-size: 223%;}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) img {width: 25%;}

.accordion ul:hover li { width: 8%; }

.active, .accordion ul:hover li:hover { width: 60%; }

.active, .accordion ul:hover li:hover a { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.active, .accordion ul:hover li:hover a * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div> <a class="null" href="#">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <p>#</p>
        </a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div> <a class="null" href="#">
        <h2><img src="images..." alt=""/></h2>
        <p>#</p>
        </a> </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Just coding out of necessity, sorry for not tagging it correctly. I'm ME, not CS.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any class named `null`. Were you trying to remove the class? If so, you can just toggle it. And you had an `else` with no `if`, which is invalid syntax.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("null");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought "null" meant the lack of a class. I usually use "case" in MatLab, not sure if it's applicable here. Thanks again!